# Ansible Exit code fail

Tags: ansible, devops

Guys I have code like:

```
- name: Running ccache for {{ SOMETHING }}
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - command1
    - command2
    - command3
  when: stat_result.stat.exists
  failed_when: >
    (rc != 0) or
    (rc != 8)
```

I tried to get the following logic work:

"If command's exit code is not 0 or 8 , then success."

However only thing I get from this is:

[0;31mfatal: [someIPhere]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(rc != 0) or (rc != 8)' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((rc != 0) or (rc != 8)): 'rc' is undefined"}[0m
Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a variable to contain the results of the commands. This variable will contain values for each item in the loop, including `rc`.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables

```
- name: Running ccache for {{ TENANT }}
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - touch /tmp/test
    - touch /tmp/test
    - touch /tmp/test
  when: stat_result.stat.exists
  register: command_result
  failed_when: command_result.rc not in [ 0, 68 ]
```